# Using Oracle APEX Interactive Report Messages in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, translation, oracle-apex, globalization

I have created a multi language APEX application in the guidance of [Oracle APEX 5.0: Managing Application Globalization](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/global.htm#HTMDB14000). I have translated all Interactive Report Messages (ie. `APEXIR_*`) to several languages. However, I cannot use/refer those messages in HTML/Javascript.

I have tried the methods mentioned in [Oracle APEX: Understanding Substitution Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03022): Neither `&APEXIR_HELP.`, nor `#APEXIR_HELP#` worked.

There is a suggestion to use `APEX_LANG.MESSAGE` in [Oracle APEX:Translating Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/global_messages.htm#HTMDB25937). However, that method seem to work with PL/SQL queries. I do not know how to use that in HTML or Javascript.

NOTE: The technical requirement is to show `APEXIR_HELP` translations in GUI. ie. "Help" must be placed in English translation and "Hilfe" in Dutch translation in place of `&APEXIR_HELP.` in the code below:

```
<span style="margin-right: 15px"><a href="&P_HELP_LINK./0&APP_ID..htm" target="_blank"><font style="text-transform: capitalize;">&APEXIR_HELP.</font></a></span>
```

Edit1: I use APEX 5.0 and the result of WWV_FLOW_MESSAGES query is:

```
FLOW_ID   NAME          MESSAGE_LANGUAGE   MESSAGE_TEXT   IS_JS_MESSAGE
113       APEXIR_HELP   en                 Help           Y
113       APEXIR_HELP   en-us              Help           Y
113       APEXIR_HELP   tr                 Yardım         Y
```

Comment: So you have an own button which will open up some link and as text has the APEXIR_HELP message text? Where are you placing this link html?

Comment: @tom Exactly. That piece of code is in header section. More precisely, it relies under
`<header id="uHeader">
  <div class="apex_grid_container clearfix">
    <div class="apex_cols apex_span_12">
      <div class="logoBar">
        <div class="userBlock">`
section of 25th template.

Comment: I have APEX 4.2, so i tried:  select *
 from APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_MESSAGES$ t
 where t.name = 'APEXIR_HELP' - it shows me two messages in two languages. Show us your result of this query (but change scheme/user)

Comment: @NoGotnu I have added the result into main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use internal messages (like APEXIR_HELP) in you html/javascript code. So, APEXIR_HELP message appeares only in IR report menu. You can translate it to your own language (via Globalization -> Text Messages), and then, it will appear in this menu already translated. If you want to use own translated messages, try this:

1. Add new message in Globalization -> Text Messages (for example: MY_HELP_MESSAGE).
2. Add new item to your page (for example P1_ITEM1), source of the item is: `APEX_LANG.MESSAGE('MY_HELP_MESSAGE', V('APP_USER'));`
3. Then use `&P1_HELP.` in you HTML/Javascript code.